# JAVA EE JSF тег <f:param> вместо параметра передает - null

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf, xhtml

На странице отображены ссылки, нажав на которую должен отображаться определенный контент. Не могу понять почему не отображается контент. При вызове метода `findId()` параметр с именем `"id_action"` не передается в Managed Bean и полю name присваивается значение `null`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить данную ошибку?
Код основной страницы **main.xhtml**

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"

 >

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Facelets Template</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="leftmen3"/>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/templates/lesson_template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <div class="content">

                <h:outputText value="#{lessonController.content}" /> 

            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Код страницы **lesson_template.xhtml**

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Facelets Template</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div>
        <ui:insert name="leftmenu">
            <ui:include src="../templates/leftmenu.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </ui:insert>
        <ui:insert name="content">
            <ui:include src="../templates/content.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Код страницы leftmenu.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
        <h:dataTable value="#{lessonController.lessonList}" var="less" >
            <h:column>
                <h:form>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{lessonController.findId()}" value="#{less.name}">
                        <f:param name="id_action" value="#{less.name}"></f:param>
                    </h:commandLink>
                </h:form>

            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>  

    </ui:composition>
```

Код Managed Bean

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class LessonController implements Serializable {

private ArrayList <Lesson> lessons;
private String content ="";
private String name ="";

public LessonController() {
    fillLessonAll();
}
private void fillLessonAll() {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    lessons = new ArrayList <Lesson> ();
    try {
         conn = DataBase.getConnection();
         stmt = conn.createStatement();
         rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from lessons");
        while(rs.next()){
            Lesson lesson = new Lesson();
            lesson.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            lesson.setLesson(rs.getString("lesson"));
            lesson.setId(rs.getInt("idlessons"));
            lessons.add(lesson);
        }
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(DataBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(conn!=null) conn.close();
            if(stmt!=null) stmt.close();
            if(rs!=null) rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LessonController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   
} 
public ArrayList<Lesson> getLessonList (){
    return lessons;
}
    public void findId() {
    Map <String,String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameterMap();
    name = params.get("id_action");
    for(Lesson less : lessons) {
        if(less.getName().equals(name)) content = less.getLesson();
    }
}
public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сам нашёл ошибку в коде класса контроллера (`LessonController`), нужно было:

```
Map params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
```

а это неверно:

```
Map params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameterMap()
```